# Your app does not post a privacy policy in the Play distributed app

Tags: react-native, google-play-console, privacy-policy

We have a https://www.dreamkid.ai/privacy-policy ,

Our application is already live on the app store, but we are unable to publish it on Google; they reject it and provide the responses shown in the photos when I inquire about the reason. I'm not exactly sure what I need to do.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the policy link to your play console as below

[image]

If you are sharing any user data from your app to any other service you would need to mention that withing the data safety section as well.

[image]

Comment: I have already added the policy link to my play console (look at last image from question I asked and I have mentioned in the 'Date Safety' section which information I have collected and shared.